# Confusion with c++ templates

Tags: c++, templates

I am working on a homework assignment that involved converting matrix and array classes supplied by my professor into templates.  I am getting an error     '=': cannot convert from 'Array *' to 'int' in my line `m[i] = new Array < Type >(cols);` 
I would assume this is because m[i] is returning an int but I don't think it should be if I wrote my templates correctly and I can't quite figure out why it is giving back an int instead of a array pointer since m is an array of array pointers here is the code to my array template minus some overloads for << not used in this code.

```
template
< typename Type >
class Array
{
private:
    int len;
    Type * buf;
public:
    Array(int newLen)
        : len(newLen), buf(new Type[newLen])
    {
    }
    Array(const Array & l)
        : len(l.len), buf(new Type[l.len])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < l.len; i++)
            buf[i] = l.buf[i]; 
    }
    int length()
    {
        return len;
    }
    int & operator [] (int i)
    {
        assert(0 <= i && i < len);
        return buf[i];
    }
}
```

Here is my matrix template the error occurs in minus the same << overloads

```
#pragma once
#include "Array.h"

template
< typename Type >
class Matrix
{
private:
    int rows, cols;
    Array< Array<Type> * > m;
public:
    Matrix(int newRows, int newCols)
        : rows(newRows), cols(newCols), m(rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            m[i] = new Array < Type >(cols);
    }
    int numRows()
    {
        return rows;
    }
    int numCols()
    {
        return cols;
    }
    Array < Type > & operator [] (int row)
    {
        return *m[row];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proximal issue is that `Array` isn't fully templated:

```
int & operator [] (int i)
```

Indexing into an `Array<T>` shouldn't give you an `int&`, it should give you a `T&`!

---

The other issue with your code is that you have a `new` in your `Array` constructor - where's the corresponding `delete`? You're leaking memory!

Same for the `Matrix` constructor, which additionally has the potential of double deleting memory if you happen to copy it.

See [Rule of Three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: Thanks  for pointing out a future issue ill add a deconstructor to stop the memory leak

Answer (score 2):

The [] operator overload in the array class is what's messing you up.

```
 int & operator [] (int i)
{
    assert(0 <= i && i < len);
    return buf[i];
}
```

It clearly returns an int as its type and when you try to use it such that: `m[i] = new Array < Type >(cols);`

m[i] will return an int type which you're trying to assign a new Array to.

Comment: Thank you! so obvious now had a hard time seeing it though

Comment: No problem. Operator overloads are one of those things that can often catch people off-guard; they've certainly bitten me.